Работают ли библиотеки (фреймворки) на Python оффлайн
Работают ли уже установленные библиотеки (фреймворки) Python в оффлайн? А то нужно сделать программу для учителя а у нас в школе не работает интернет. У меня кстати телефон и использую Pydroid 3

В целом - работают. Но для установки библиотек интернет будет нужен. Если вы на телефоне разрабатываете, и на нем же будете программу показывать - по идее проблем нет, можно протестировать работу отключив wifi и мобильный интернет. Если нужно на компе без интернета (без возможности установить библиотеки) запустить свою программу - нужен либо pyinstaller (заранее упаковать в один запускаемый файл, причем pyinstaller запускать на той же ОС, что и на нужном компе), либо выкачать файлы библиотек, потом их установить.

Спасибо, то есть когда уже установил фреймворк его, можео использовать в оффлайне?

В общем да, но могут быть какие-нибудь исключения, завязанные на работу с интернетом (какие-нибудь библиотеки, использующие онлайн перевод или получение данных из википедии, или еще что-нибудь). Обсуждать абстрактно без указания конкретного фреймворка нет смысла.

Смотря какой фреймворк.

А спасибо мне просто нужны были time, os

Эти спокойно работают. Они вообще встроенные, они ставятся вместе с питоном и им потом уже ничего больше не нужно.
